# Vuejs draggable - arggh

Tags: vue.js, drag-and-drop, draggable, vue-component

I'm new to Vuejs so please be patient. I'm trying to implement the Vuejs Draggable component and I'm stuck. I've simply copied the sample script from the Draggable website and can't get it to work.

Here is my code.

```js
<template>
<div>
    <h2>Draggable Wrapper</h2>
    <draggable v-model="exampleList">
        <div v-for="text in exampleList" :key="text">
            {{ text }}
        </div>
    </draggable>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import draggable from 'vuedraggable';

export default {
    components: {
        draggable
    },

    data() {
        return {
            exampleList: [
                'Item 1',
                'Item 2',
                'Item 3',
                'Item 4',
                'Item 5'
            ]
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I am able to see the div(s) with data, but can't drag them. Any ideas? I'm stumped.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dede89/t3m5krea/) works, but doesn't use single file components. Are you importing Sortable? I assume it comes in as a dependency, but it's the only obstacle that I ran into.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks. I was trying to get it working on a single component, but this will do for now. THANKS!!!